# What would my Higher National Diploma be considered in the United States?

Tags: united-states, university, united-kingdom

I am currently studying my BTEC HND(Higher National Diploma) from a United Kingdom approved centre and i was planning to apply to the United States after complete this diploma. However i have no information of what to expect out of the United States. What will my diploma be considered in the country and will it be easy to apply to universities regarding my discipline. I've added a link below explaining and introducing HND for those who are not fimilar with the program. 
Thank You in Advance

[Infromation about HND From Pearson Education](https://qualifications.pearson.com/en/qualifications/btec-higher-nationals.html)

Answer (score 2):

From the [website](https://qualifications.pearson.com/en/qualifications/btec-higher-nationals.html):

> BTEC Higher Nationals are internationally-recognised Higher Education qualifications at level 4 and 5 that are equivalent to the first and second years of a university degree, providing progression to both university and employment.

This means it will probably be considered as something like an [associates degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associate_degree). Some 4-year US universities might give you credit towards undergraduate classes. I doubt any well-respected university would give you credits towards a graduate degree. It is probably insufficient to get admitted directly to a graduate program.